# iteration inside page script with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, iteration

i need to insert (json) objects into an array used in a page. I'm using nodejs with jade and suppose that the code below might fit my purpose, but it doesnt work.

```
    //this code is in the template:
    script.
        otherPlayers = {};
        each player in playerList
           otherPlayers["#{player.playerId}"] = !{JSON.stringify(#{player})};
```

In the page the expected result is:

```
<script>
    otherPlayers = {};
    otherPlayers[0] = {"playerId": 0, "playerName": "Leo" };
    otherPlayers[1] = {"playerId": 1, "playerName": "Daniel" };
    otherPlayers[2] = {"playerId": 2, "playerName": "Lucas" };
</script>
```

Any hint is well accepted.
Thanks in advance at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as below in your template file.

```
//In the template file
script.
    otherPlayers = {};
    var cplayerList = !{JSON.stringify(playerList)};
    for(player in cplayerList) {
        otherPlayers[cplayerList[player].playerId] = cplayerList[player];
    }
    console.log(otherPlayers);
```